# HttpContext.Current.Session is mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am converting a asp.net project to mvc 4 razor project. I do not know how I will use the below code and I do not want to use SESSION anymore.

```
public static XmlNode Session_Class_Set
    {
        get
        {
            return (XmlNode)HttpContext.Current.Session["Class_Set"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Class_Set"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Could someone help me how I can use the code without using Session.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what would you replace Session with  ? simply remove the line using Session and replace with the line/code which uses your alternate method (a db call /reading from another xml file ?)

Comment: Nothing wrong with Session. It's still used in MVC projects.

Comment: Thanks, if I use, I need to add System.Web but it return me null value when I used System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Class_Sets_Node"] = value;, do I am missing something

Comment: @buffjape: It's still available in MVC projects, but "nothing wrong with" it, is an entirely different matter. If there's a good use case for why this should be in the session, that's one thing, but the OP definitely shouldn't just keep it there because it's expedient and "works". The session should always be avoided if you can get by with it.

Comment: Sure Chris. I was just pointing out that removing session was not an essential part of the ASPX to MVC conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different options apart from using Session;

1. Get/Post (if the amount of data is small/insensitive)
2. Cookies (same as above)
3. Database (if larger/more sensitive data)

Although I would question why you do not want to use Session. You would need to provide more information about what Class_Set actually is and how it is used for us to recommend the best solution in this case.

Comment: Class_Set returning some XML nodes like [0[ {Attribute, Name="a", Value="1"}, [1] {Attribute, Name="b", Value = "2"} like this. I just feel it will be better not to use Session and there might be something better than Session. Thanks